# Typing listing in SWI-prolog and pressing enter does nothing

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

I'm going through the prolog tutorial [here](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pageid=online) and it tells me to type in listing for a list of the contents of the current knowledgebase. I'm pretty sure that without loading a KB, it should display gibberish. However, instead I have:

[image]

after I press enter, which does nothing. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You need to put a dot (`.`) after every statement.

Comment: I feel like an idiot now. Thanks! :)

Comment: Please add this as an answer and mark this question as resolved so it's not hanging in the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each statement in Prolog must be followed by a '.' in order to be executed.